# Spring Batch 3 Classifier is not getting called

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am struggling with this issue since long time, has anyone faced this kind of issue?
I need to call writer based on certain condition so i am trying to use Classifier however my classifier is not getting called and non of the writters are getting called. I am using Spring Batch 3

I am struggling with this issue since long time, has anyone faced this kind of issue?

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration implements SqlConstants {

@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Notification> reader() {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Notification> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<Notification>();
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setSql(SqlConstants.SQL_GET_ALL_NOTIFICAITON_TO_BE_SENT);
    reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Notification.class));
    return reader;
}

@Bean
public NotificationItemProcessor notificatonProcessor() {
    return new NotificationItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Notification> notificationWriter() {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Notification> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Notification>();
    writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Notification>());
    writer.setSql(SqlConstants.SQL_SET_NOTIICAITON_STATUS_TO_SENT);
    writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return writer;
}

@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Notification> exchangeWorkflowWriter() {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Notification> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Notification>();
    writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Notification>());
    writer.setSql(SqlConstants.SQL_INSERT_EXCHANGE_WORKFLOW);
    writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return writer;
}

@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Notification> exchangeWriter() {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Notification> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Notification>();
    writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Notification>());
    writer.setSql(SqlConstants.SQL_INSERT_EXCHANGE);
    writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return writer;
}

@Bean
public DummyWriter doNothing() {
    return new DummyWriter();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
public ItemWriter<Notification> compositeExchangeWriter() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    BackToBackPatternClassifier classifier = new BackToBackPatternClassifier();
    classifier.setRouterDelegate(new ExchangeWriterRouterClassifier());

    classifier.setMatcherMap(new HashMap<String, ItemWriter<? extends Notification>>() {
        {
            put(ExchangeRouter.INSERT_EXCHANGE_FOR_NOTIFICATION.getActionName(), exchangeWorkflowWriter());
            put(ExchangeRouter.INSERT_EXCHANGE_FOR_PACK.getActionName(), exchangeWriter());
            put(ExchangeRouter.DO_NOTHING.getActionName(), doNothing());
        }
    });

    ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Notification> writer = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Notification>();
    writer.setClassifier(classifier);
    return writer;
}

@Bean
public Job generatePdf(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("generatePdf")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(treatStock())
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step treatStock() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("treatStock")
            .<Notification, Notification>chunk(1)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(notificatonProcessor())
            .writer(compositeExchangeWriter())
            .build();
}
```

}

Comment: I understood the issue since i had 2 writer it was causing the issue,however i want to have 1 writer which should execute in any condition and other 2 writer should execute based in certain condition. how do i achieve this? do i have to create one more steps just to execute another writer ?

Comment: I see your similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435285/using-compositeitemwriter-the-writer-or-classify-method-is-not-getting-called

There is no enough input to see why it's not working, If you share a runnable project, we would love to help.

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine for the detail explanation, after removing 2nd writer `compositeExchangeWriter` is getting invoked. but i also need to execute `notificationWriter` Do i have to have another step for write operation?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine here is the git repository i have created for the project. https://github.com/jigarsnaik/spring-batch/tree/master in this example how do i invoke `notificationWriter()`

Comment: ok glad it helped! have you tried to add the `notificationWriter` to the composite writer? Now that your composite is invoked correctly, you can add the `notificationWriter` as a delegate in the composite and it should be invoked.

Comment: But if i add notifierWriter as a delegate than it will only execute one of the writer based on the map key. I want this notification writer to be executed without any condition.

Comment: In that case, you need to create a composite writer composed of your `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` + your `notificationWriter`